# What have been the most lethal zoonotic disease in recent years?

Tags: covid-19, zoonotic-viruses

Zoonotic diseases like covid-19 arise from an animal host which then often passes it to another animal host where it gets amplified to create sufficient viral load to jump to humans. eg. Bat droppings eaten by civets then causing sars.

What are the most recent lethal virus diseases that have done this?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> The new type of coronavirus has had a greater proliferation in a shorter amount of time than its predecessors SARS and MERS. However, the percentage of deaths remains much lower. Nearly 10 percent of those infected died during the SARS outbreak, while 35 percent died during MERS.

MERS is still an active disease in its region, but SARS was wiped out from the human population.

From Aljazeera https://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/interactive/2020/03/covid-19-charts-maps-200310163714493.html

Comment: I didn’t know about NIPAH until I saw this visual. It has such a scary mortality rate and has had outbreaks as recent as 2018 https://www.who.int/csr/don/07-august-2018-nipah-virus-india/en/